Inspecting celery tasks in Django
Is importing Celery app and calling control.inspect() the best way for inspecting active tasks? Also, I'm using RabbitMQ as my broker.
My current way of doing it:
from core.celery import app

# django view
def get_running_tasks(request):
    i = app.control.inspect()
    i.active() # retrieving active tasks


What do you mean by active tasks? Tasks that are currently running or tasks that are registered?

use flower to monitor task. checkout the documentation https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

@KryštofŘeháček Tasks that are currently running

@Tanveer I need to do it in python code, for something like API purposes to show tasks state

Then you have to implement web sockets that will sends current state of your celery tasks.

I think that I will stay with my current approach. Thanks for all the help and suggestions
